# Overflow:hidden and overflow-y: scroll on ul not working;

Tags: html, css

I have the below HTML and CSS to be able to scroll down a list, and I cannot figure out why the `overflow:hidden` and `overflow-y: scroll` are not working on the ul.

I have tried all kinds of things such as taking out the div in between the `.interaction-box` and the ul, and making interaction-box an id, but they did not work. The styling does work on the outer div but the title gets scrolled along with the list.

What am I missing?

```css
.interaction-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 360px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.interaction-box ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.search-result {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div className="interaction-box">
   <div className="interaction-title">Top Search Results
   </div>
   <ul>
     <li className="search-result">Result</li>
     <li className="search-result">Result</li>
     <li className="search-result">Result</li>
     <li className="search-result">Result</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please generate a live demo or fiddler It will be easy to analyse the issue!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to give your `ul` a height so it has a reference when to start making the element scrollable. If it has no height, then it will just go on forever and the scrollbar will never be applied.

```css
.interaction-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 360px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.interaction-box ul {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.search-result {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="interaction-box">
  <div class="interaction-title">Top Search Results</div>
  <ul>
    <li class="search-result">Result</li>
    <li class="search-result">Result</li>
    <li class="search-result">Result</li>
    <li class="search-result">Result</li>
    <li class="search-result">Result</li>
    <li class="search-result">Result</li>
    <li class="search-result">Result</li>
    <li class="search-result">Result</li>
    <li class="search-result">Result</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
<div class="interaction-box">
   <div class="interaction-title">Top Search Results
   </div>
   <ul>
     <li class="search-result">Result</li>
     <li class="search-result">Result</li>
     <li class="search-result">Result</li>
     <li class="search-result">Result</li>
     <li class="search-result">Result</li>
     <li class="search-result">Result</li>
     <li class="search-result">Result</li>
     <li class="search-result">Result</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.interaction-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 360px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.interaction-box ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.search-result {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```